# Prove $\{X\in S^n_+ | \langle A,X \rangle =a, \langle B,X\rangle =b, \langle C,X\rangle =c\}$ is bounded

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, inner-products, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming

I've been busting my brains about proving the following theorem:

> Given that $A,B,C\in S^n$ with $n\geq3$, and that for some $\alpha, \beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$ it holds that $\alpha A+\beta B+\gamma C\succcurlyeq 0$,  show the set $K=\{X\in S^n_+ \mid \langle A,X \rangle =a, \langle B,X\rangle =b, \langle C,X \rangle=c\}$ is bounded.

Where ofcourse $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the matrix inner product $\langle X,Y \rangle = \sum\limits_{i,j=1}^n X_{i,j}Y_{i,j}$

Comment: Where is this theorem stated? It seems like the claim is false when $A=B=C$, although since your requirements on $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are a ambiguous I can't tell if that case is omitted. What do you mean by $\alpha, >\beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: That was a type-o, sorry, now it is fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Theorem is false. Consider
$$A = B = C = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 
 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \text{ and } a = b =c = 1. $$
Then $A+B+C \succeq 0$, but the set $K$ is not bounded. For example,
$$X_M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & M & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \in K \quad \forall M \geq 0,$$
and clearly,
$$ \lim_{M \to \infty} \| X_M\| \to \infty.$$

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot about $n \geq 3$, my bad! Your addition would work, thank you!